# Memcached parameter checking

Tags: memcached

For some reason at the moment memcache it causing a spike in the response time of the site.

[in other questions with memcached numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464615/are-these-memcached-stats-normal) cmd_get = get_hits + get_misses 
`STAT cmd_get 6236962
STAT get_hits 6236962
STAT get_misses 6543342`

for some reason in our setup cmd_get is equal to get_hits and get_misses is larger than cmd_get. When I try to run stats malloc I get an error which seems weird.

the result is really slow tranactions that can take 30 seconds to execute memcache set and get

## Questions #

1. Why would my cmd_get = get_hits?
2. Why is my get_misses higher than my cmd_get?
3. How can I debug what is causing the spikes in response time?

stats

`STAT pid 18998
STAT uptime 10603
STAT time 1334538670
STAT version 1.4.2
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 225.370000
STAT rusage_system 717.590000
STAT curr_connections 613
STAT total_connections 1884098
STAT connection_structures 1306
STAT cmd_get 6236962
STAT cmd_set 2517801
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT get_hits 6236962
STAT get_misses 6543342
STAT delete_misses 234263
STAT delete_hits 247387
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT bytes_read 6593604547
STAT bytes_written 3999518494
STAT limit_maxbytes 6442450944
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT bytes 1417582141
STAT curr_items 549532
STAT total_items 2517801
STAT evictions 0`

stats slab

`.........
STAT 25:chunk_size 21696
STAT 25:chunks_per_page 48
STAT 25:total_pages 33
STAT 25:total_chunks 1584
STAT 25:used_chunks 1570
STAT 25:free_chunks 0
STAT 25:free_chunks_end 14
STAT 25:mem_requested 30429185
STAT 25:get_hits 1265
STAT 25:cmd_set 3844
STAT 25:delete_hits 0
STAT 25:incr_hits 0
STAT 25:decr_hits 0
STAT 25:cas_hits 0
STAT 25:cas_badval 0
STAT 26:chunk_size 27120
STAT 26:chunks_per_page 38
STAT 26:total_pages 9
STAT 26:total_chunks 342
STAT 26:used_chunks 305
STAT 26:free_chunks 0
STAT 26:free_chunks_end 37
STAT 26:mem_requested 7494861
STAT 26:get_hits 1308
STAT 26:cmd_set 3876
STAT 26:delete_hits 0
STAT 26:incr_hits 0
STAT 26:decr_hits 0
STAT 26:cas_hits 0
STAT 26:cas_badval 0
STAT 27:chunk_size 33904
STAT 27:chunks_per_page 30
STAT 27:total_pages 32
STAT 27:total_chunks 960
STAT 27:used_chunks 280
STAT 27:free_chunks 673
STAT 27:free_chunks_end 7
STAT 27:mem_requested 7980338
STAT 27:get_hits 43377
STAT 27:cmd_set 115313
STAT 27:delete_hits 0
STAT 27:incr_hits 0
STAT 27:decr_hits 0
STAT 27:cas_hits 0
STAT 27:cas_badval 0
STAT active_slabs 26
STAT total_malloced 1692051984`

Answer (score 0):

why are you using memcached 1.4.2 version, the latest is 1.4.13. It can be a bug in the release but i will be difficult to find out, as most of the system are using the far latest version. I was also facing an issue not of the same nature but related to the memory leaks, therefore we upgraded it and the issue went away. This may not be the answer but still people can help if the problem persist on the latest memcached version also.